# How to check if indesign is running or hanged?

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm calling Adobe InDesign through C# via COM, to execute some scripts for converting to PDF files, but some times the files are too big and they can take more than 3 minutes to be converted, also it can convert multiple files together, so it takes time, how can i know that InDesign is not hanging and it is still running?

Comment: You can implement logging in your script which will log data during the life cycle , lets say you have multiple files to work on so in your script write logs that file one exported , file 2 exported this way you can check it is still working

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid thanks, but the problem is that if the file takes too long, it might be that indesign is hung, so what i did is setting a timeout, but i was looking for a more efficient way to do it.